# Using a Custom Keyboard on Android Application

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm currently developing an Android Application and I read about creating Custom Keyboards for Android, so I decided to create my own Custom Keyboard.

After doing some research, I successfully created and tested on an Android Emulator with API 19, the result look like this:

(Because of my reputation (I'm a "noob" in this community) I can't post images, but here's a link for an image of the Custom Keyboard)

[Custom Keyboard (ES)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1FI0.png)

Where "Mayus" Key is for "Shift", "Borrar" Key is for "Erase", "Espacio" Key is for "Space bar" and "Hecho" Key is for "Done".

Well, I'm pretty satisfied with the results and functionality of the Custom Keyboard and I want to implement it into my Android Project.

How can I use (import/call) this Custom Keyboard into my Android Application?

What are the modifications or line codes I need to implement for this to work?

By the way, I only have 1 EditText in my Android Project, so I need to call my Custom Keyboard only for 1 activity (1 layout).